# How to get a text which is after the image tag, and that image tag placed with in a div... using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This is my Div. I want to get the text "I want to get this text" which is inside a div but follows by an image tag . Can anyone please help me!!!!

```
<div class="showAttachmentDiv"><img class="recentCloseImg" src="./wp-content/themes/rivng/images/closePopUp_2.png" />I want to get this text</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: paste your tried code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
alert($(".showAttachmentDiv").text());
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/xhDrY/)

Answer (score 0):

use image class selector and `text()`
try this

```
 $('.recentCloseImg').text(); //from img
 $(".showAttachmentDiv").text(); //from div
```

however , it is better you use an id and use id selector to be specific

```
 <img id="recentCloseImg" class="recentCloseImg" src="./wp-content/themes/rivng/images/closePopUp_2.png" />

 $('#recentCloseImg').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Img has no text property  so it will good write **[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** in this parent div its show text in a div

```
$(".showAttachmentDiv").text(); //show "I want to get this text"
```

if you use **[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** then show html in a div

```
 $(".showAttachmentDiv").html(); //show <img class="recentCloseImg" src="./wp-content/themes/rivng/images/closePopUp_2.png" />I want to get this text
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('div.showAttachmentDiv').text();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F9YRh/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $('.showAttachmentDiv').text();
```